# Get name by translated string from resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resx

I want to get the name of a translated string by its value from RESX file in .NET Core 3.1.

I Know the below code is answer but how do I access to RESX file correctly?

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = 
    new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.Views.Shared._Layout.de.resx", this.GetType().Assembly);

return await Task.Run(() => rm.GetResourceSet(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true)
      .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
      .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Value.ToString() == value).Key.ToString());
```

My resource files are scaffolded as below.

[image]

And the error message is as below.

[image]

What is the right addressing to the RESX files in this case?

Comment: The resx file is binary and data from the resx is loaded into the parent class.  So any property values can be accessed in the parent class.

Comment: Hi @Mehdi,any update about this case?If my answer is helpful to you, can you mark it as an answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you will look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you will see that ASP.NET Core has introduced IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizer.

Under the cover, IStringLocalizer use ResourceManager and ResourceReader. Basic usage from the documentation:

```
 public class StringLocalizerController : Controller
{
  
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

    public StringLocalizerController(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName);
        localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public IActionResult SharedResource()
    {
        return Content(localizer["AAA"]);
    }
}
```

Start up:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources/View/Shared");
```

Result:
[image]
[image]